# How to use group by in md-select in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to bind the below data to the dropdown in two group. one is Text File and another one is RDBMS Category[image: dropdown image].

1) Text File

a) AWS

b) Azure

c) Mainframe

2) RDBMS

a) Oracle

b) Sybase

c) Teradata

d) MySQL

e) SQLServer

f) DB2

```
<md-input-container>
        <md-select name="databaseType" ng-change="databaseTypeChange()" ng-model="form.databaseType" class="input-div" required ng-disabled="update && view">
          <md-option  ng-value="databaseType" ng-repeat="databaseType in databaseTypes | groupBy:'databaseType.Category'">{{databaseType.Subcategory}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
        <div ng-messages="DataAccessRoleForm.databaseType.$error">
          <div ng-message="required">required</div>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>

$scope.databaseTypes.push({ "ID": template_id, "Category": category, "Subcategory": template_name, "JsonSchema": schema });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle it with filter filter mate. Get the group name for md-optgroup by having ng-repeat on it & reducing the options array object. so your html coded will look like

```
<md-select ng-model="selection" placeholder="Select an Option">
  <md-optgroup label="{{currentGroup}}" ng-repeat="currentGroup in groupList">
    <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {group: currentGroup}">{{item.name}}</md-option>
  </md-optgroup>
</md-select>

$scope.groupList = $scope.items.reduce(function(previous, current) {
if (previous.indexOf(current.group) === -1) {
  previous.push(current.group);
}
  //console.log(previous);
  return previous;
}, []);
```

Here's a working plunker for your requirement

http://plnkr.co/edit/ApuUq7V88ad6uplKjKSC?p=preview

Now this's not as elegant as group by of ng-options but it works fine.